# Downloading Ubuntu for installation on an HP laptop

Tags: system-installation

I need to change the OS from MS Windows to Ubuntu on my daughter's laptop.  I am considering burning a Ubuntu disk with my Apple desktop (Imac) computer.  Is this possible because Apple does not seemlessly mersh with Windows based machines (software architecture don't you know).  I tried to do this once already, but the windows laptop did not recognize the CD.  Am I better off just trying to burn a CD for Ubuntu with the laptop instead?  PUZZLED

Comment: How about an USB?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine if you're using an ISO image.  Make sure you're burning the entire IMAGE, and not the FILES *in* the image.

Answer (score 0):

When you burn a disc, you have to make sure the filesystem is closed in order to make it bootable (or 'mastered'). The CD can be closed or left open ('packet writing') and other uses.